# $\nabla f$ is tangent to $G$-orbits vs trajectories of the $\nabla f$ lies in the $G$-orbit

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields

This is a screenshot of page 5 of the article called "Matsuki correspondence for sheaves"
[image]

Here $f$ is a smooth function defined on a Riemannian manifold $X$ and $\nabla f$ is the gradient vector field of $f$.

I was thinking that saying that "the vector field $\nabla f$ is tangent to $G$-orbits" is the same as saying that "the trajectory of $x$ by the gradient flow $\nabla f$ lies in the $G$-orbit $G.x$" but reading this passage in page 5, I realize that it is not, anyone explain the difference between the two statements, please ?

In general, if $M$ is a manifold and $N$ is a submanifold of $M$. Let $\xi$ is a vector field on $M$. What is the difference between saying that $\xi$ is tangent to $N$ and saying that at each point $x$ the flow of $\xi$ lies in $N$ ?

Comment: Is there any further assumption relating $f$ and the $G$-action? As it is, we cannot say anything.

Comment: @Didier, $f$ is $G$-invariant. Does this help?

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, and should contain everything that it involves: relevant properties of $G$, $f$, etc. In particular, the fact that $f$ is $G$-invariant must be settled in the question. Also, I'm not really sure that this is the right assumption: $f$ being $G$-invariant means that the $G$-orbits lie in the level sets of $f$. And it is known that $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to these level sets. So $\nabla f$ should be orthogonal to the $G$ orbits in that case, not tangent.

Comment: @Didier, $f$ in the article is the norm square of a moment map, and it is $G$ invariant.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and settle *everything* that is relevant? People wanting to help you might not want to look for all these information by themselves

Comment: @Didier, I have edited my question, I hope it is clearer now.